# django-filer, easy_thumbnails and S3: images are saved but thumbs aren't

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set up my S3 storage backend with django-filer. When I upload an image through the filer admin interface the image is actually uploaded (I can see it in my bucket/filer_public/...), however, what I see on the clipboard is "undefined" and no icon of the image. I can't see the preview in the Change Image view neither, although the link "Full size preview" is right and when I click it I can see the image from S3.

Looks like the only problem is that easy_thumbnails is not able to upload the files to S3, I've tried many different settings (like setting THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_STORAGE) but nothing works, and anyway, I think the defaults should work out of the box.

I'm using django-filer 0.9.4, Django 1.4.3, easy_thumbnails 1.2 and Python 2.7.

My settings:

```
####### S3 Storage setup ########
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that i installed PIL (or Pillow) without JPEG support. To fix that, I just had to install libjpeg-dev and reinstall PIL:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
sudo pip install -I Pillow
```